# I don't see anything related to how to write code to put the swiffy swf.html file in my webpage

Tags: iframe, google-swiffy

I have already used the iframe tags with no luck, it just plays in a separate window instead of on the page.  I got a tip to use the div tags to create a swiffy container then this code at the end of the body tag.

```
<script>

 var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
 swiffyobject, {  });
 stage.start();
</script>
```

This does not play on the page and I get a 404, but if I type in the path to the swiffy file, it plays in a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `<script>swiffyobject = ...</script>` part of the swiffy.html file in your page as well as the part you have in your question. It's going to be a lot of hard to read code. I would just put it before the closing body tag.